# react + mongodb port

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

I'm trying to build react app with mongoDB. React app is running on port 3000
and when i'm running server.js for mongodb on the same port, my app is overriten.

How do I make mongoDB to run on same port?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the web server and database on the same port. The convention is to use the next port, ie 3001 for Mongo.

It doesn't actually matter which port Mongo runs on, as long as your app knows about it

**UPDATE**

Run mongo with a command like this:

```
mongod --dbpath=/home/me/mydata --port 3001
```

If you are using npm package mongodb, connect like this

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL 
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:3001/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I make my app to know about it?